# Bounded operator on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ is a Hilbert space. If $T\in B(H)$ show that $T+T^*\ge 0$ iff $T+I$ is invertible in $B(H)$ with $\|(T-I)(T+I)^{-1}\|\le 1$.

(Hint is  $T+T^*\ge 0$ iff  $\|(T+I)x\|\ge \|x\|\ $ and 
$\|(T+I)x\|\ge \|(T-I)x\|\ $.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020),  [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T+\mathbb 1$ is invertible and $\|(T-\mathbb 1)(T+\mathbb 1)^{-1}\|≤1$. Then you have:

$$(T^\mathstrut-\mathbb 1)(T^*-\mathbb 1)=T^\mathstrut T^* - T^* - T^\mathstrut +\mathbb 1 =(T\mathstrut+\mathbb 1)(T^*+\mathbb 1)-2(T^\mathstrut+T^*)$$

And then you get

$$2(T\mathstrut+T^*)=(T^\mathstrut+\mathbb 1)(T^*+\mathbb 1)-(T^\mathstrut-\mathbb 1)(T^*-\mathbb 1)$$

Multiply both sides from the left by $(T+\mathbb 1)^{-1}$ and from the right by $(T^*+\mathbb 1)^{-1}$ (call these $B$ and $B^*$ to simplify the expression) to get

$$2B(T^\mathstrut+T^*)B^*=\mathbb 1-B(T^\mathstrut-\mathbb 1)(T^*-\mathbb 1)B^*$$

Now note that $B(T^\mathstrut-\mathbb 1)(T^*-\mathbb 1)B^*$ is of the form $F^\mathstrut F^*$ for $F=B(T-\mathbb 1)$. This means that it is a *positive* operator. Furthermore, from $\|F^\mathstrut F^*\|=\|F\|^2$ you get: 
$$\|B(T^\mathstrut-\mathbb 1)(T^*-\mathbb 1)B^*\|=\|(T^*-\mathbb 1)(T^*+\mathbb 1)^{-1}\|^2≤1$$

So $2B(T^\mathstrut+T^*)B^*=\mathbb 1-A$, where $A$ is positive and has norm smaller than $1$. This means $B(T^\mathstrut+T^*)B^*$ is positive.

If you have a positive operator $P$, then $B^{-1}P(B^{-1})^*$ is also positive. If you take $P=B(T^\mathstrut+T)B^*$ and apply this you get that $T^\mathstrut + T^*$ must be positive. This would conclude the first direction.

---

For the second direction let $T+T^*≥0$, then $$(T^\mathstrut+T^*)+T^*T^\mathstrut=(T^*+\mathbb 1)(T^\mathstrut+\mathbb 1)-\mathbb 1$$ is a sum of positive operators, and thus positive. Remember that if a hermitian operator $P$ is positive, then $P+ \epsilon I$ is invertible for any $\epsilon >0$ (this is actually the usual definition of positive in $*$ algebras). For that reason
$$(T^*+\mathbb 1)(T^\mathstrut+\mathbb 1)=(T^\mathstrut+T^*)+T^*T^\mathstrut+\mathbb 1$$ is invertible. The same argument shows that $(T^\mathstrut+\mathbb 1)(T^*+\mathbb 1)$ is invertible.

If $AB$ and $BA$ are invertible, then $A$ and $B$ must both be invertible. To see this consider for example $A^{-1}:=B(AB)^{-1}$, then
$$A(B(AB)^{-1})=(AB)(AB)^{-1}=\mathbb 1$$ and
$$B(AB)^{-1}A=B(AB)^{-1}A \ (BA) (BA)^{-1}=B(AB)^{-1}AB A (BA)^{-1}=BA(BA)^{-1}=\mathbb 1$$
so you get that $(T+\mathbb 1)$ and $(T^*+\mathbb 1)$ are invertible.

To get the bound we have to turn the first proof around. We have from $T^\mathstrut+T^*$ being positive that $2B(T^\mathstrut+T^*)B^*$ is positive, which is equal to $\mathbb 1-B(T^\mathstrut-\mathbb 1)(T^*-\mathbb 1)B^*$. But the thing we are subtracting from $\mathbb 1$ is positive, so for the subtraction to result in a positive thing, what we are subtracting must have norm smaller than $1$.

What we are subtracting is however

$$(T+\mathbb 1)^{-1}(T-\mathbb 1) \cdot (T^*-\mathbb 1)(T^*+\mathbb 1)^{-1}$$

Which has norm $\|(T^*-\mathbb 1)(T^*+\mathbb 1)^{-1}\|^2$, for this to be smaller than one it must be true that $\|(T-\mathbb 1)(T+\mathbb 1)^{-1}\|≤1$ holds.

Comment: is this T* adjoint operator?

Comment: @user319271 yes.

Comment: @user319271 I have edited the post to be more legible and to account for more basic explanations, if you are having trouble with any point let me know.